# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property ... Using @OneToOne annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a hibernate entity joined to other using on @OneToOne annotation.
But when try use criteria I get `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: username` exception.

My dao method:

```
public PasswordResetToken getPasswordResetToken(String username) {

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(PasswordResetToken.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("username",username));

    List<PasswordResetToken> tokens = criteria.list(); // <- exception

    if (tokens.size() > 0) {
        return tokens.get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

PasswordResetToken Entity:

```
@Entity
public class PasswordResetToken {

    private static final int EXPIRATION = 60 * 24;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

     @OneToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "username")
     private User user;
     ...
```

Database table:

```
Table: PasswordResetToken
Columns:
id  bigint(20) AI PK
expiryDate  datetime
token   varchar(255)
username    varchar(45)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field name is `user`

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("user", username));
```

Comment: Thanks, plus   `getPasswordResetToken(String username)`  -> String to User :)